# Ways for accessing / including template files

Tags: c#, file

I'm currently designing a mail application that uses html templates that are being loaded for specific mailtypes and then replaces placeholders within the files. I'm currently trying to find out what ways there are for accessing these files or where to best put them.

Currently in the solution/project structure I have the following layout:

```
MyProject
   |----> Auxiliary
               |----> MailTemplates
                           |-----> MyMailTemplate.html
```

Naturally when I use File.Exists("Auxiliary\MailTemplates\MyMailTemplate.html" ) that fails as the "debug" or "release" folder is the current folder on execution and not the Base folder of the project itself.

The plan is that I read the whole text of the template file and put it into a String variable against which I replace the placeholders and then use the result for the mailbody.

```
String templateContent = File.ReadAllText(mailTemplatePath);
```

So my question is mostly how can I include / access the template files without having to rely on the file/application being in a specific fixed (and not altering) path?

Comment: you could map a repository folder(where you will store your template) with a setting key then concatenate with your file path

Comment: You can use an appsettings key or other key to point to the templates directory (TEMPLATE_ROOT maybe) or you could also use #if DEBUG (or whatever) and have it select the appropriate path based on compilation constants. There are other ways.

Comment: in total those methods would have as requirement that the files are in a fixated directory or am I mistaken there?